# Frequency range of interest in PCB decoupling network

Tags: capacitor, pcb-design, decoupling-capacitor, decoupling

All the material I found about decoupling write "[...] low impedance in the *frequency range of interest* [...]" but it's never discussed how this is defined. Does it come from

1. The external noise on the supply network that should be filtered
   in going into the chip?
2. The frequency range of the *current drawn by the chip* such that this current faces a low-impedance?

**If it's the first (1)**: That does not usually depend on a particular chip since the noise is external. And how would I know the frequency range of the noise? For example, if I use my cellphone close by (or even have RF parts closeby) this may couple into my supplies. So ideally I would like to filter up to multi-GHz no matter what. But I find it is extremely hard to get a PCB decoupling network (using 0402) that's not inductive for more than some hundred MHz.

**If it is the second (2)**: Suppose I have a (mixed signal) chip with a) some digital logic, operating at 100 MHz, b) some analog amplifier, operating at up to 1 GHz. The 2 blocks have different supplies.

For a) the fundamental of the current draw will be 100 MHz. However, the current drawn are current spikes, so the frequency content is very high (as opposed to just 100 MHz). For that reason, again, I would like to cover multi-GHz, which is not possible.

For b) there is essentially no (significant) ac current drawn. This would imply no decap is necessary at all. Clearly this is not true, since analog chips also have decaps. Then, if **(1)** is correct (and I assume the noise has infinite bandwidth), it means that my decoupling network would need to work up to 1 GHz. But again, this is not reasonable.

So how exactly is this frequency range *of interest* defined and what do I do if the *interesting frequency* exceeds 1 GHz - far more than PCB coupling can cover?

Answer (score 0):

> It all depends on the analog noise specs for Vcc or Vdd or Vca or Vcd and also the return path with load current specs. This can be understood by impedance ratios for range of frequencies from DC to 0.35/Tr.

Both conditions may apply depending on what the IC needs and uses.

1) external ripple and bandwidth, load current and attenuation needed, which implies an impedance ratio or transfer function s12(f)  for any RLC network and breakpoint.

2) self generated ripple. Any dI/dt from CMOS switched capacitance into a R=ESR+Z(f) supply generates V=IR for duration t.  At low f, an LDO at DC a load regulation spec which rises in frequency due to declining GBW feedback where several shunt caps are used to flatten the Zo response. Parasitic inductances and ultra low ceramic ESR *can* cause spurious resonace, if not careful so wide low ESL caps are used often UHF or in combination with lossy ferrite beads.  For low current applications an RC filter may be adequate with suitably small cap with high SRF.

Generally I would recommend impedance or spectrum analyzers to verify a design and calculate by dynamic impedance ratios for source and dynamic load to determine what noise is self induced by each source and if necesary model with s-parameters for each passive part with traces for UHF.  Noise pulse currents with small duty cycle with pulse width with < 1/2 fmax if possible to inject noise currents into the design to analyze effective absorption from C, ESL and ESR.

Search TDK low ESL caps with higher ESR to prevent spurious resonance.

You can use f-3dB =0.35/tr for range of interest vs rise time.

> For some designs, embedded capacitance PCB power gnd planes make sense which requires high quality thin dielectric.
>   https://www.google.ca/search?q=buried+capacitance+pcb&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=mkKTWsriHfDQXsjWupAN